# Is not knowing the correlation enough to allow using a new aspect of already-analyzed data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Long version of this question's context is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MagicArena/comments/b21u3n/i_analyzed_shuffling_in_a_million_games/).

I am attempting to analyze the shuffling in the card-based online game Magic Arena, which I suspect is unintentionally biased in a particular way. I have no access to either the code for this shuffling or the servers it runs on. What I do have is data from over a million games, collected client-side.

I have already looked at many charts drawn from this data, focusing on a particular type of card called lands. The charts I have examined show distribution of number of lands in the first N cards from a shuffled deck that contains L lands and C cards. I found that the bias in these distributions, relative to expectations for a correct shuffler, follows a noticeable pattern depending on L and C, but I had not predicted this pattern in advance.

I now plan to do a followup analysis focusing on position in a list that I believe is used as the order of the deck as it is input to the shuffler, essentially replacing "lands" with "the first ~24 cards in the input order". I believe that there is a significant correlation between the positions of lands in that order and the combination of L and C, partly because I have an explanation for why the correlation would exist, and partly because what I believe about that correlation combined with what I suspect about the cause of the observed bias fits the patterns I found. I have not, however, seen any data regarding that correlation directly, nor made any *numerical* assessment of how strong it would have to be to match those patterns.

Does my lack of definite and/or numerical knowledge about that correlation make it valid to use the same games in my followup analysis, where I plan to make and test numerical predictions about the pattern of bias based on position in the input order without using that correlation in the calculations? My exact choice of hypothesis for the cause of bias was informed by qualitative assessment of the correlation and the previous analysis, but the numerical predictions will be derived directly and exclusively from that potential cause.

Comment: In most cases you don't have this kind of knowledge about the data. If I were you, I'd be more concerned about the data itself. You said that it's gathered on client-side. I guess that with this kind of games it is hard to find sample that is random and representative. There's probably lots of self-selection involved.

Comment: @Tim The gathering is done automatically by a tracking program that people use primarily to track their own play history. Most users of it keep it running while they play, effectively making the decision to report each game before the game even starts. Even for recording games afterward, this project has not been publicized, so most people would not factor it into the decision to do so. Even for people who might consider it, a card's position in the input order is not obvious in the game, so they'd have to do significant additional investigation to even be able to self-select in a biased way.